# Smarty encoding UTF-8 / ISO-8895-1

Tags: encoding, smarty

i have a smarty array with the following values / keys (simplified):

```
$smartyArray => array(
    'wei�' => 'Color',
);
```

But my "selector" for the key has the correct encoding:

```
$keyToSelect = 'weiß';
```

Both were deliverd by PHP. The goal is, to encode the key in the array by `$keyToSelect`

```
$smartyArray[$keyToSelect] => 'Color';
```

How can i transform the "�" to a simple "ß" - in smarty without php?

Comment: You cannot transform "�" to ß; you need to handle encodings correctly within your system so you're never in a situation to see a "�" to begin with. Where do these two kinds of data originate from?

Comment: As i said - that array comes from a php function. The point is, that the key was okay by dumping the array on php side. No encoding problems. The whole site has utf-8 charset.. After dumping the array on clientside / smarty, i've got these encoding problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

deceze is right, but I guess you could use something like this http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.to_charset.tpl

Comment: That's what i am searched for.